# connect to the internet through other computer's wireless ethernet card

Tags: linux, windows, internet

there are two computer

wireless internet accessible notebook.

desktop with no wireless card (but just normal lan card).

I connect two computer with lan cable, and I want to use internet in desktop computer through the notebook's wireless lan

what kind of setting do I have to do?

desktop's OS is Ubuntu, and notebook's one are Ubuntu, Windows XP.

Comment: I swear I've seen a question just like this before. Try searching around; see if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure you laptop and desktop like this:

Laptop:

```
IP: 192.168.0.1
MASK: 255.255.255.0
```

Desktop:

```
IP:192.168.0.2
MASK:255.255.255.0
GATEWAY:192.168.0.1
```